# get parameter from url in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I want to get parameter from url in angularjs. for that i have did following.
1. in my app.js

```
var app = angular.module("testApp",
    ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider 
            .when('/subscribe/:statusResponse', {
                templateUrl: "client/subscription/statusResponse.html",
                controller: "testController"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/"
            });

    // use the HTML5 History API
   // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

2 in controller file:

```
app.controller("testController",['$routeParams',function($routeParams){
    console.log($routeParams.statusResponse);}]);
```

3. in html file right now i have added simple text with define testApp.

The problem is that 
when i hit url in browser

app.dev/demoapp/#/subscribe/test

it automatically grab 
app.dev/demoapp/#/subscribe/:statusResponse

so what should be the problem i am not able to find that?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @BonMacalindong its not working

Comment: check in `Console` in dev tools in Chrome for errors, and in `Network` tab to check if it's fetching `statusResponse.html`

Comment: in console it prints  ":statusResponse" not the value what i have passed and also url is also contains ":statusResponse" rather than what i have written and it fetches the html file

Comment: You have a missing `)` after `function($routeParams`. You should really be developing with your browser's console open **all the time**

Comment: What URL are you going to in your browser? It should look something like `#/subscribe/someValue`

Comment: @phil yes fill i have updated my quetion and also added those url in that please check that